# Filter group of pattern inside array in perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, filter

How do I filter and collect a group of pattern inside array using regex ?

search pattern is `.include 'pathToFile'` where `pathToFile` have to be stored into `@include` array.

```
my @include = grep {$4 if /^\s*\.(inc)(l(ude)?)?\s+'(\S+)'/i} @fileContent;
```

Unfortunately my code doesn't store only `$4` which is the include file path. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `map` each item in the `@fileContent` to the capture `$4` and only then `grep` to find only matching ones:

```
my @include = grep {!/^$/} map {/^\s*\.(inc)(l(ude)?)?\s+'(\S+)'/i && $4} @fileContent;
```

By the way, the first three capture groups are redundant, so you may rewrite the regex with only capture group `$1`:

```
my @include = grep {!/^$/} map {/^\s*\.inc(?:l(?:ude)?)?\s+'(\S+)'/i && $1} @fileContent;
```